# Is there a way to disable auto fill for forms on website?

Tags: html

I have only recently learned to create websites using `HTML` and `PHP`.

I have created a website that has a quiz where people are asked to translate words at random.  The user inputs their answers into a form, and the website evaluates the answer as correct or incorrect.

Now when a question is asked twice in a session, auto-fill shows up, allowing people to see their previous submissions.  However for people trying to test their memory this isn't good.

I know I can turn off auto-fill in my browser, but is there a way I can adjust the `PHP` or `HTML` code so that auto-fill is automatically turned off for this particular form?

Comment: You can use JavaScript to disable the auto-fill, here the library: https://github.com/terrylinooo/disableautofill.js

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`autocomplete="off"` should do the trick!

Put this in your `<form>` tag or in every `<input>` tag like this:

```
<form autocomplete="off" />
<!-- OR -->
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="Text" />
```

Comment: Great...really nice catched !!!

Comment: Thanks for answering, I didn't realize it was a duplicate.  I will accept your answer after the 10 minutes required.

Comment: Note: Autocomplete and Autofill are completely different things

Comment: its not working in some browser..after clear caches its work.... its another trick is available without clear caches browser?

Answer (score 3):

For each `input` field add

```
autocomplete="off"
```

So:

```
<input type="text" name="demo" autocomplete="off" value="test" />
```

See  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

Also this maybe a duplication of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I didn't realize it was a duplicate.  I wish I was the first to post the answer, it has 300 up votes.

Comment: There's lot's of questions like that wish I always wish I had the rights too :P