# How to disable the Saved Username/Passwords automatically filled

Tags: jquery, razorengine

Able to disabled the autocomplete

[image]

Is it possible for all browser !!!!

Login my application

[Entering Username and Password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ams1k.png)

and the Asking Like [Clicked the Save button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBwR3.png)

Then logout the application. after few seconds i  going to login... [Its automatically filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klVjf.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to disable auto fill for forms on website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725332/is-there-a-way-to-disable-auto-fill-for-forms-on-website)

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

autocomplete="off" role="presentation" use it in form tag

Comment: <label for="emailFld">EMail Address</label>
  <input id="emailFld" readonly type="email" onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) { this.removeAttribute('readonly');    
    this.blur();    this.focus();  }" />
  <br/>
  <label for="pwdFld">Password</label>
  <input id="pwdFld" readonly type="password" onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) { this.removeAttribute('readonly');
    this.blur();    this.focus();  }" /> <br/> give a try with this

Comment: **<label for="emailFld">EMail Address</label> <input id="emailFld" readonly type="email" onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) { this.removeAttribute('readonly'); this.blur(); this.focus(); }" /> <br/> <label for="pwdFld">Password</label> <input id="pwdFld" readonly type="password" onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) { this.removeAttribute('readonly'); this.blur(); this.focus(); }" /> <br/>** Working fine. While hover the mouse on the text box red color icon is disturbing